# AWS get-object doesn't create local directories

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface, cloud

I am trying to download a file from S3 compatible storage and I am running the following command:

```
aws s3api get-object --endpoint-url https://my.endpoint.url/ --bucket my_bucket --key mailouts/m3/ma2.png mailouts/m3/ma2.png
```

And I get and error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'mailouts/m3/ma2.png'
```

However, when I run the following command:

```
aws s3api get-object --endpoint-url https://my.endpoint.url/ --bucket my_bucket --key mailouts/m3/ma2.png ma2.png
```

i do end up with `ma2.png` file in my current directory. So it looks like `aws cli` cannot create intermediate directories `mailouts/m3`

Is there a way to force `aws cli` to make local directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use `aws s3 cp` command, it will create needed folders.

Answer (score 2):

Not when retrieving a single file. The [sync](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) command in the AWS S3 CLI will create directories in the destination as long as there is at least one file in the directory. You can use the `--include` and `--exclude` options to narrow down the files synced (even down to just `ma2.png`) if you do not want to sync the entire directory tree.

Answer (score 0):

S3 buckets do not have directories/folders. When you have something like:

mailouts/m3/ma2.png

that is just a filename in your S3 bucket. If you want to save ma2.png in ./mailouts/m3, you have to parse the object name and create the intermediate folders/directories yourself.